# SignalR HTTPS client

Tags: c#, signalr, internet-explorer-10, self-hosting, owin

Using SignalR 0.53 and self-hosting with OWIN, I was able to have an HTTPS client connect successfully to a non-HTTPS localhost port.

I have now upgraded to SignalR 1.1.2.

I have enabled cross-domain have have non-HTTPS clients connecting successfully. However, now it seems that an HTTPS client will be blocked.

Note: I also have to use IE10. 
This appears in the console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://localhost:9100/signalr/hubs
```

An alert with "SignalR: Error during negotation request: undefined" is displayed.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a fix in the end. The security issue was a red herring. Under normal circumstances on IE10 it will use jsop and give this message:

"SignalR: Using jsonp because this browser doesn't support CORS"

However, with this particular client this was not happening. Specifying the use of jsonp explicitly when connecting fixed the issue.

```
$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp : true },function () { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just standard [mixed-mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx) connection blocking. When you're on a page that is HTTPS, all the resources from it should be HTTPS or else you could be tricked into sending data in the clear even though you're thinking you're on a secure page. So the browser (IE at least) is protecting you by not allowing this form of mixed-mode communication. If your page is HTTPS, your SignalR connections will also need to be HTTPS.

Comment: I already have mixed-mode enabled in IE. That cant be whats causing the issue.

Comment: Well, that's what the SEC7111 error is telling you. You don't have to take my word for it: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SEC7111.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I'm just puzzled as to why it was working in a previous setup. I would have thought enabling mixed-mode would be enough but clearly it isn't.

Comment: Well, are you sure you configured it for the Int*ra*net Zone specifically?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm going to host the hubs file on HTTPS as a workaround. Thanks